# Why are somes class not generated in a binding project?

Tags: java, .net, xamarin, osmdroid

I'm trying to bind a project with **Xamarin Studio** so I successfully removed the errors and it bind correctly !

**BUT** some class are not generated in C#. Why ?

I worked with the Metadata.xml to bind correctly the name of the package -> [PICTURE](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/18/1430657738-metadata.png)

and it allowed me to use this JAR (osmbonuspack) in my project.
At compile, I have some warning message like : "class ... matched no nodes. (error code : BG8A04). -> [PICTURE](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/18/1430658725-warnings.png)

I think it is because of this warning that I can't use these new class in my project ! -> *[PICTURE in comment below]*

And i know that these class exist (I used JD-Gui to see the class in the JAR) -> *[PICTURE in comment below]*

So, **why** Xamarin doesn't bind correctly some class ?

**PS** : Sorry, I can't post more than 2 links so I post in comment the next screenshot

Comment: Activity picture : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/18/1430657737-activity.png and JD-Gui picture : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/18/1430657737-jdgui.png

Comment: Can you share your project?

Comment: Of course, here it is : https://github.com/Nawako/osmbind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found the problem.
Sample project is [here](https://github.com/halkar/osm.binding) (sorry for the mess in folders structure). I had to add gson jar to solve problem with converting KmlDocument methods that use it. Xamarin is "terrific" as always. You may have noticed a huge number of warning during the binding generation. It appears that some of them are real "errors" and some of them tell you that Xamarin wasn't able to generate some classes (KmlDocument for example).

Answer (score 0):

First and main problem is that you have three jars in one binding project. I don't know if that is an Android binding limitation or I don't know but I never managed to create binding project for more than one jar. So my suggestion is to create three separate binding projects. That should help.

Comment: According to [Xamarin guide](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/binding_a_java_library_%28.jar%29/) : "However multiple EmbeddedJar and EmbeddedReferenceJars can be specified as needed."

Comment: Can you share projects after splitting up?